# Enable authorization in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I created some mongodb users and when I tried to enable Authorization I added this directive

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

to /etc/mongod.config file, and when I restarted mongod it won't start and it exited with error.

My mongodb is version 5.x as a replicaset of three nodes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: what about posting your error message ?